# T4MVC, is it outdated? Still good? If not what else to use?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, mvccontrib, t4mvc, asp.net-mvc-futures

Folks,

*As of today* should I introduce T4MVC in my project or use strongly typed goodness from MvcContrib?

```
return RedirectToAction(MVC.MyController.MyAction());
```

or

```
return RedirectToAction<MyController>(c => c.MyAction());
```

Trying to stick with standard/mainstream and stay up to date.

I know, there are Q&A on this site, I am interested to hear what is latest & greatest, rather than what was 2 years ago.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We are using ReSharper 6 in all of our MVC projects and with the [MVC support](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/asp_net_editor.html) and nice refactoring tools we never had any problems with using strings as action and controller names. So 1 vote for none of them :)

Comment: @nemesv Thanks, good observation. Sorry for leaving no choice, I didn't really consider this option having used to externalize every possible magic from applications. I am coming from non-web world, so its understandable. Thanks again.

Comment: Resharper doesn't cater to HtmlHelper.GenerateLink, etc, which is a larger pain point of refactoring than Redirect methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both techniques are acceptable today and I haven't heard that one would be deprecated. `T4MVC` has the advantage of performing better which is one of the reasons why those strongly typed helpers taking lambda expressions are actually not part of the ASP.NET MVC core.

Comment: thanks for prompt response. Does it mean T4MVC is a clear-cut choice, or it has some disadvantages? or ask another way, if there's T4MVC around, why strongly typed helpers are even created?

Comment: Those are subjective questions that I cannot answer. Some people prefer T4MVC, others prefer the strongly typed helpers and some are just happy with magic strings.